# MVC model is null when posting json in ASP.Net Core

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

All relevant code:

```
//JSON data
var dataType = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
var data = {
    FirstName: 'Andrew',
    LastName: 'Lock',
    Age: 31
}

console.log('Submitting form...');
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Diary/Save',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: dataType,
    data: data,
    success: function (result) {
        console.log('Data received: ');
        console.log(result);
    }
});


[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Save([FromBody] Person person)
{
    return Json(person);
}



public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

"person" in the Save method is always null.  This should work...it feels perhaps like a settings issue?  Do I need to make changes here:

```
 services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
        });
```

Comment: I do this in the Ajax method.. data: JSON.stringify(dataType), then in the controller action I take out [FromBody]

Comment: I think there's other jiggery you have to do in .net core to make it work without [FromBody] (I've tried your suggestion anyway though, still all nulls)

Comment: You're posting to `/Diary/Index` but the function is called `Save`. Is this just an error in the post here or are you running this specific code?

Comment: Error in the post sorry, thanks

Comment: Why did you write `contentType: dataType`? You cannot reference the property above it like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to stringify the data that you are sending to the server to convert it to JSON because that's the content type header you indicated:

```
data: JSON.stringify(data)
```

Comment: What the ACTUAL hell?! I spent hours on this going round and round various combinations of this - I have previously added JSON.stringify, and it's not worked...so what have you done?  C'mon, own up, you've been here?

Answer (score -1):

Please Try This Solution : 
**In Jquery File :**

```
var data = {firstname : 'ali', lastname: 'alavi', age: 31};
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('data',JSON.stringify(data));

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",        
        url: controllerUrl, //something like ~/[ControllerName]/[ActionName]
        data: formData,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success)
                // ...
            else
                // ...
        },
        error: function () {
            // log error ...
        }
    });
```

**Then In Your Controller try :**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
.
.
.
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult CreateServicesPost(string data)
 {
     var personModel = new PersonModel();
     personModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PersonModel>(data);
      // ...
 }
```

**And Your Perso Model Is :**

```
public class CreateServicePostModel
{
        public string Firstname{ get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
}
```