# JSON.stringify Passing Into Razor-Page As Null

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a asp.net core razor-page where I am trying to read the data off of a table and pass it into a my controller so that I can process changes made in the table. I've checked other similar questions on this site like this one: [MVC model is null when posting json in ASP.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42297519/mvc-model-is-null-when-posting-json-in-asp-net-core)
but I keep getting a null value in the razor-page. I'm posting the relevant code below. If there is something else that you need to see please let me know.

Ajax Call Below:

```
 //--------------------------------------------------------------------
 // Load Up An Array and Pass the Data To The Razor Page
 //--------------------------------------------------------------------
 $('#UpdateScoresButton').click(function () {
   // Store Data in an Array
    var enteredScores = new Array();
   // Loops through whole table
   $("#table tbody tr").each(function () {
     // Grabs Each Row
       var row = $(this);
       var score = {};
       score.DeputyID = row.find("td").eq(0).html();
       score.DivisionID = row.find("td").eq(1).html();
       score.QuarterID = row.find("td").eq(2).html();
       score.PrimaryModelID = row.find("td").eq(3).html();
       score.SecondaryModelID = row.find("td").eq(4).html();
       score.ShotgunModelID = row.find("td").eq(5).html();
       score.RifleModelID = row.find("td").eq(6).html();
       score.PrimaryFirstScoreID = row.find("td").eq(7).html();
       score.PrimarySecondScoreID = row.find("td").eq(8).html();
       score.PrimaryThirdScoreID = row.find("td").eq(9).html();
       score.SecondaryScoreID = row.find("td").eq(10).html();
       score.ShotgunScoreID = row.find("td").eq(11).html();
       score.RifleScoreID = row.find("td").eq(12).html();

       enteredScores.push(score);
});    

$.ajax(
    {
        url: '/EnterScores/Enter_Shooter_Scores?handler=InsertUpdateAndReloadData',
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(enteredScores),
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.pass != undefined) {
                document.forms[0].submit();
            }
        },
        error: function (result, exception) {
            console.log(result);
            // Your error handling logic here..
        },
    });
});
```

Here is the razor-page code:

```
public JsonResult OnPostInsertUpdateAndReloadData([FromBody] List<EnteredScores> enteredScores)
{
  var test = enteredScores;            
  return new JsonResult(new { pass = "Pass" }); ;
}
```

My EnteredScores Class :

```
 public class EnteredScores
{
    public int DeputyID { get; set; }
    public int DivisionID { get; set; }
    public int QuarterID { get; set; }
    public int PrimaryModelID { get; set; }
    public int SecondaryModelID { get; set; }
    public int ShotgunModelID { get; set; }
    public int RifleModelID { get; set; }
    public int PrimaryFirstScoreID { get; set; }
    public int PrimarySecondScoreID { get; set; }
    public int PrimaryThirdScoreID { get; set; }
    public int SecondaryScoreID { get; set; }
    public int ShotgunScoreID { get; set; }
    public int RifleScoreID { get; set; }     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the properties in EnteredScores are int type.You need to pass int type data to handler.Try to change

```
       score.DeputyID = row.find("td").eq(0).html();
       score.DivisionID = row.find("td").eq(1).html();
       score.QuarterID = row.find("td").eq(2).html();
       score.PrimaryModelID = row.find("td").eq(3).html();
       score.SecondaryModelID = row.find("td").eq(4).html();
       score.ShotgunModelID = row.find("td").eq(5).html();
       score.RifleModelID = row.find("td").eq(6).html();
       score.PrimaryFirstScoreID = row.find("td").eq(7).html();
       score.PrimarySecondScoreID = row.find("td").eq(8).html();
       score.PrimaryThirdScoreID = row.find("td").eq(9).html();
       score.SecondaryScoreID = row.find("td").eq(10).html();
       score.ShotgunScoreID = row.find("td").eq(11).html();
       score.RifleScoreID = row.find("td").eq(12).html();
```

to

```
        score.DeputyID = parseInt(row.find("td").eq(0).html());
        score.DivisionID = parseInt(row.find("td").eq(1).html());
        score.QuarterID = parseInt(row.find("td").eq(2).html());
        score.PrimaryModelID = parseInt(row.find("td").eq(3).html());
        score.SecondaryModelID = parseInt(row.find("td").eq(4).html());
        score.ShotgunModelID = parseInt(row.find("td").eq(5).html());
        score.RifleModelID = parseInt(row.find("td").eq(6).html());
        score.PrimaryFirstScoreID = parseInt(row.find("td").eq(7).html());
        score.PrimarySecondScoreID = parseInt(row.find("td").eq(8).html());
        score.PrimaryThirdScoreID = parseInt(row.find("td").eq(9).html());
        score.SecondaryScoreID = parseInt(row.find("td").eq(10).html());
        score.ShotgunScoreID = parseInt(row.find("td").eq(11).html());
        score.RifleScoreID = parseInt(row.find("td").eq(12).html());
```

And since you passed data is json type,you need to add `contentType: "application/json",` to your ajax like this:

```
$.ajax(
    {
        url: '/EnterScores/Enter_Shooter_Scores?handler=InsertUpdateAndReloadData',
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        },
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(enteredScores),
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.pass != undefined) {
                document.forms[0].submit();
            }
        },
        error: function (result, exception) {
            console.log(result);
            // Your error handling logic here..
        },
    });
```

result:
[image]

Comment: This answer worked for me. Thank you very much for presenting it so that i understand what I missed. I'll mark yours as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is likely due to model binding failing. Looking over this code, the first issue I'd address is the difference been the Javascript object names [that you're passing up to your C#/MVC action] and the "EnteredScores" model/class properties. The easiest refactor would be to edit your Javascript code like so:

```
score.DeputyID = row.find("td").eq(0).html();
score.DivisionID = row.find("td").eq(1).html();
score.QuarterID = row.find("td").eq(2).html();
etc.
```

Change the above [your orginal code] to the below [my refactor of that code], just make sure you update all fields so they match.

```
DeputyID = row.find("td").eq(0).html();
DivisionID = row.find("td").eq(1).html();
QuarterID = row.find("td").eq(2).html();
etc.
```

Comment: I'll test this out and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: I tried this one out as well and it didn't change the outcome for me. The parse int seems to be the correct answer. Thank you for taking the time to look at my issue though.